# Regex to extract first 10 characters of a string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

There are two scenarios

**First case:**

I have an html string for example,

```
 var str1="<b>hello how are you</b><h1>how to extract the first 10 characters of a htmlstring without losing the html of the string</h1>";
```

I have to extract the first 10 characters of a string without loosing the html. So that the expected output is

```
<b>hello how a<b>...
```

**Second Case:**

I have a simple string as below

```
var str1="hello how are you.how to extract the first 10 characters of a htmlstring without losing the html of the string";
```

I have to extract the first 10 characters of a string . So that the expected output is

```
hello how a...
```

I want an regex expression thact could be applied for both these cases.

I am new to regex.. I have tried a lot but I dont have any working code so that I could post it here.Please help.

Comment: @aelor expected output is **hello how a**..

Comment: Why do you need a regex for that? Won't `substring` be sufficient if you need 10 chars (as I understand always) ?

Comment: Is `&quot;` one character or 6?

Comment: You want to cut the first 10 characters but preserve element nesting? e.g. output would be `<b>hello how a</b>`?

Comment: @lpiepiora then I will lose html

Comment: you have two h1 closing tags.

Comment: @alex Yes I want that as output so only I represented it in bold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of [your rephrased question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422951/regular-expression-to-extract-10-characters-of-a-string);

Regexp is not a good tool for handeling html.

The proper way is to parse the DOM.  Jack gives an example of this, but with the assumption that the markup you want to keep is the first child of the node you are looking at.

The question I link above indicates that this is not the case.  However Jack's solution can be adapted to handle arbitrary nesting.  I do this by simply counting characters of the nodes until I get to the break point.  Then recursivly modifying the final node.  Finaly I drop all nodes that occur after the required number of characters have been found.

```
function getNodeWithNChars(capture,node)
{
  var len=node.childNodes.length;
  var i=0;
  var toRemove=[];
  for(;i<len;i++)
  {
     if (capture===0)
     {
       toRemove.push(node.childNodes[i]);
     }
    else if (node.childNodes[i].textContent.length<capture)
    {
       capture=capture-node.childNodes[i].textContent.length;
    }
    else
    {
      if(node.childNodes[i].childNodes.length===0)
      {
        node.childNodes[i].textContent=node.childNodes[i].textContent.substring(0,capture);
        capture=0;
      }
      else
      {
        node.childNodes[i]=getNodeWithNChars(capture,node.childNodes[i]);
        capture=0;
      }
    }
  }
  i=0;
  for(;i<toRemove.length;i++)
  {
    node.removeChild(toRemove[i]);
  }
  return node;
}

function getNChars(n,str)
{
  var node = document.createElement('div');
  node.innerHTML = str;
  node=getNodeWithNChars(n,node);
  return node.innerHTML;
}
```

Example of invocation of the above function;

```
console.log(getNChars(25,"hello how are <b>you</b> <em>how <b>to extract the</b> first 25 characters of a htmlstring without losing the html of the string</em>"));
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your effort very much, Thanks a lot, But I have done it when @Taizo Ito notified me about that it cannot be done in regex,May be It will be useful for me somehow, Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
var str1="<b>hello how are you</b></h1>how to extract the first 10 characters of a htmlstring without losing the html of the string</h1>";
var res = str1.replace(/<(.*?\>)(.{11}).*/, '<$1$2</$1');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: In line attributes and values might mess with that…

Comment: @aleor , but when I give the input without html its not working

Comment: you said your expected output is `<b> hello how a <b>` so i gave yo that

Comment: @aelor, sorry the input may be with or without html.. Please help.. am so sorry that i didnt specify

Comment: can you plese add one or two scenarios and expected output in each case , that willl be really helpful

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
regex = /(<[a-z0-9]+>|)([a-z0-9 ]{0,10})[a-z0-9 ]*(<\/[a-z0-9]+>|).*/

str1 = "hello how are you.how to extract the first 10 characters of a htmlstring without losing the html of the string"
console.log(str1.replace(regex, '$1$2$3'))

str1 = "<b>hello how are you</b><h1>how to extract the first 10 characters of a htmlstring without losing the html of the string</h1>"
console.log(str1.replace(regex, '$1$2$3'))
```

Comment: @ Thank you, but how could I change the number of characters to lets say 50

Comment: but Can you help me to change the number of characters to 100

Comment: Just change '{0,10}' to '{0,100}'.

Comment: var regex = /(<[a-z0-9]+>|)([a-z0-9 ]{0,100})[^\<\>]*(<\/[a-z0-9]+>|).*/;

Comment: Your str1 includes other characters than alphabet, number and blank.

Comment: Try this: var regex = /(<[a-z0-9]+>|)([^\<\>]{0,100})[^\<\>]*(<\/[a-z0-9]+>|).*/;

Comment: Taizo lto could you help me sir

Comment: var regex =  /(.*<[a-z0-9]+>|)([^\<\>]{0,100})[^\<\>]*(<\/[a-z0-9]+>|).*/;
Maybe you should use HTML parser if you want to deal with HTML text correctly.

Comment: Thank you sir, I appreciate your effort...I will choose your suggestion of html parser too... Thank you so much